# Site query does not exist .... Request URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Tags: python, django

I have done this .. cant figure out the error

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> site = Site.objects.create(domain='example.com', name='example.com')
```

but still getting error help me what to do I' m trying to access auth_views.login and admin

> python shell error..

```
C:\Users\MOIZ\Desktop\theme\fproject\fproject>python mannage.py runserver
python: can't open file 'mannage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\MOIZ\Desktop\theme\fproject\fproject>python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> Site.objects.create(name='example.com',domain='example.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MOIZ\Desktop\theme\fproject\fproject\env\lib\site-packages\djan
go\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\MOIZ\Desktop\theme\fproject\fproject\env\lib\site-packages\djan
go\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_site.domain

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MOIZ\Desktop\theme\fproject\fproject\env\lib\site-packages\djan
go\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
```